# Ruby Array Union - Controlling which object is chosen

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am trying to merge two arrays of objects in ruby. The objects have two relevant fields; **id** and **reach_cost**.

I want my resultant array to contain unique ids, where each object has the smallest reach_cost in the case of a collision.

Running;

```
result = a1 | a2;
```

Yields mixed results, it appears that elements of **a1** take precedence over elements of **a2**.

I could of course iterate over both arrays and make the comparison on **element.reach_cost** manually, but this is a high performance environment, and this method gets called an awful lot. For that reason I am trying to leverage the native components of the | operator.

Is it possible to direct the | operator to prefer one object over another? Perhaps by overriding <=> or similar?

I have read the source code of the | operator in the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html) but it doesn't appear to make any comparison, merely preferring the first array parameter over the second.

Comment: Perhaps, it would be better to store these arrays as hashes. This way you have O(1) access by id (and can use naive double loop)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for the suggestion, I will certainly take that approach if the double-loop is the only option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest storing these arrays as hashes. This provides O(1) id lookup. Here's what the code may look like:

```
h1 = {'1' => {:val => 2}, '2' => {:val => 3}}
h2 = {'1' => {:val => 5}, '2' => {:val => 1}}

def merge_hashes a, b
  a.reduce({}) do |memo, obj|
    k, v = obj

    # choose element with smallest :val
    memo[k] = if b[k][:val] < v[:val]
                b[k]
              else
                v
              end

    memo
  end
end

merge_hashes h1, h2 # => {"1"=>{:val=>2}, "2"=>{:val=>1}}
```

This should work pretty fast.

If you like one-liners, here's one (kindly provided by @steenslag in the comments):

```
h1.merge(h2){|key,old,new| old[:val] < new[:val] ? old : new}
```

Comment: Hash#merge takes a block, something like `h1.merge(h2){|key,old,new|[old,new].max}` should do it (untested).

Comment: Hmm, better:`h1.merge(h2){|key,old,new|old[:val]>new[:val] ? old : new}`.

Comment: Thanks. This sure is shorter :)

Answer (score 3):

The solution is simple, but you need to check the performance for yourself:

```
result = a1.concat(a2).sort_by!(&:reach_cost).uniq!(&:id)
```

Comment: He said that it is called ofthen, not that is contains enormous amount of data. The performance is an issue of course, it must be benchmarked, but it is a oneliner solution anyways. :)

Comment: nice solution, thanks matzi. I should have specified - memory is not much of an issue, its more execution time that we're trying to minimise, so some temp arrays are fine.

Comment: you can use `!`  and `concat` instead of  `+` to avoid creating tem arrays :)